# my typegoose save function didn't return needed type (NodeJs, typescript, graphql)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, graphql, typegoose

My function save of an object **(in model.ts file)** which is created by typegoose should return `Promise<Todo>` but it returns `Promise<Document<any, {}>>`
and i have this error :

```
Type 'Document<any, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'Todo': createdAt, updatedAt, content, isDone
```

How should i correct this ?

**model ts**

```
import { getModelForClass } from "@typegoose/typegoose";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

import { Todo } from "../../entities";
import { NewTodoInput } from "./input";

// This generates the mongoose model for us
export const TodoMongooseModel = getModelForClass(Todo);

export default class TodoModel {
  async getById(_id: ObjectId): Promise<Todo | null> {
    // Use mongoose as usual
    return TodoMongooseModel.findById(_id).lean().exec();
  }

  async create(data: NewTodoInput): Promise<Todo> {
    const todo = new TodoMongooseModel(data);

    return todo.save();
  }
}
```

**input ts**

```
import { Field, InputType, ID } from "type-graphql";
import { MaxLength, MinLength } from "class-validator";

@InputType()
export class NewTodoInput {
  @Field()
  @MaxLength(300)
  @MinLength(1)
  content: string | undefined;

}
```

**entities todo ts**

```
import { ObjectType, Field } from "type-graphql";
import { prop } from "@typegoose/typegoose";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

@ObjectType()
export class Todo {
  @Field()
  readonly _id!: ObjectId;

  @prop()
  @Field(() => Date)
  createdAt!: Date;

  @prop()
  @Field(() => Date)
  updatedAt!: Date;

  @prop()
  @Field()
  content!: string;

  @prop({ default: false })
  @Field()
  isDone!: boolean;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the unofficial mongoose types, it is an known problem that `await document.save()` does not return the correct typings
-> this is not an problem with typegoose, it is with `@types/mongoose`

the workaround is to use:

```
await doc.save();
return doc;
```

(or maybe in your case directly use the mongoose provided function `.create`)

PS: this is not a problem in the official types of mongoose (can be currently used with typegoose `8.0.0-beta.x`)